# Building a list of objects out of another list of lists parsed from a JSON file

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to build a page showing Open Street Map with routes. I've set up the OSM, and the routes/polylines should be added through a list of LatLng objects (an object consisting of two doubles marking the latitude and longitude of points connected by a line). What I want to do is fetch the user's location, and then get the latitudes and longitudes of the path along the route from the user's location to some other location, through the use of the Graphhopper API.

JSON returned from the API is as follows:

```
{  
   "hints":{  
      "visited_nodes.average":"40.0",
      "visited_nodes.sum":"40"
   },
   "info":{  
      "copyrights":[  
         "GraphHopper",
         "OpenStreetMap contributors"
      ],
      "took":5
   },
   "paths":[  
      {  
         "distance":689.229,
         "weight":408.670174,
         "time":496240,
         "transfers":0,
         "points_encoded":false,
         "bbox":[  
            15.23345,
            44.103858,
            15.238698,
            44.105704
         ],
         "points":{  
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[  
               [  
                  15.238079,
                  44.103858
               ],
               [  
                  15.238369,
                  44.104135
               ],
               [  
                  15.238698,
                  44.104337
               ],
               [  
                  15.238349,
                  44.104658
               ],
               [  
                  15.238155,
                  44.104889
               ],
               [  
                  15.237904,
                  44.105114
               ],
               [  
                  15.237713,
                  44.105236
               ],
               [  
                  15.237051,
                  44.105388
               ],
               [  
                  15.236858,
                  44.105457
               ],
               [  
                  15.236894,
                  44.105388
               ],
               [  
                  15.236866,
                  44.105314
               ],
               [  
                  15.236739,
                  44.105209
               ],
               [  
                  15.235663,
                  44.104713
               ],
               [  
                  15.234928,
                  44.105129
               ],
               [  
                  15.234886,
                  44.105037
               ],
               [  
                  15.234913,
                  44.10476
               ],
               [  
                  15.234786,
                  44.10476
               ],
               [  
                  15.234449,
                  44.105039
               ],
               [  
                  15.23355,
                  44.105704
               ],
               [  
                  15.23345,
                  44.105639
               ]
            ]
         },
         "legs":[  

         ],
         "details":{  

         },
         "ascend":2.619999408721924,
         "descend":3.4739990234375,
         "snapped_waypoints":{  
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[  
               [  
                  15.238079,
                  44.103858
               ],
               [  
                  15.23345,
                  44.105639
               ]
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Basically, I need to create a list of LatLng objects from this JSON ( an example: `[LatLng(15.236866, 44.105314), LatLng(15.23355, 44.105704)]` ), but, sadly, I have no clue how to do this. Any help, advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried searching through the web and hacking some code together, but I'm afraid that it didn't prove to be of much help.

```
Future<Points> _fetchCoordinates() async {
  final response = await http.get(
    'https://graphhopper.com/api/1/route?point=44.1035042,15.2385878&point=44.105091,15.2318734&vehicle=foot&locale=hr&key=<API_KEY>&points_encoded=false&instructions=false',
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Points.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Error');
  }
}

class Points {
  List<List<double>> coordinates;

  Points({this.coordinates});

  factory Points.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Points(
      coordinates: List<List<double>>.from(json["paths"]["points"]
              ["coordinates"]
          .map((x) => List<double>.from(x.map((x) => x.toDouble())))));

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "coordinates": List<dynamic>.from(
            coordinates.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(x.map((x) => x))))
      };
}

class Routing extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Points>(
      future: _fetchCoordinates(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        final List coordinates =
            snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data.coordinates : <LatLng>[];
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return MyCustomMap(
            lat: 44.1035042,
            lng: 15.2385878,
            points: <List of LatLng objects, for example: [LatLng(41.234, 
              43.465)]>,
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return [...]
        } else
          return [...]
      },
    );
  }
}
```

It appears that there's some error in my code; statement that's returned is located in the "else if (snapshot.hasError)" clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `LatLng` class like this:

```
class LatLng {
  double lat;
  double lng;

  LatLng(this.lat, this.lng);
}
```

then you can decode the json like this:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> decoded = json.decode(j);
  List<dynamic> co1  = decoded['paths'][0]['points']['coordinates'];
  List<LatLng> coords = co1.map((pair) => LatLng(pair[0], pair[1])).toList();
```

You could still have a `Points` class that wrapped the `List<LatLng>`...

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much! I really do appreciate it.